# Why don’t verbs following can take -ing?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Verbs following **can** don’t take **-ing**. We can say:

> I can fly

but we don’t say:

> I can flying

I’m not sure what the rule behind this is. I have a feeling it’s to do with auxiliary verbs and/or helping verbs. I have a faint recollection of auxiliary verbs being followed by straight verbs but I’m not sure if this rule has a name or not.

Ideas?

Comment: *Can* is a [modal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb). Modal verbs are always followed by [infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive) (first form of the verb).

Comment: Right. That's the straightforward answer. The modal verbs -- _can, could, shall, should, will, would, may, might, must,_ and sometimes _need_ and _dare_ -- must be followed by **infinitive** (plain, present) verb forms, and not by _-ing_ (participial, gerund) verb forms, or any other form of verb. No _to_ is used before the infinitives, either. Modals are **weird**.